# Latest version of Zxing.net.forms.mobile in Xamarin does not execute scan

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I have a Xamarin app that is trying to implement Zxing.Net.Mobile & Zxing.Net.Mobile.Forms
When trying to use the ZxingScannerView ScanResultCommand never executes.... it does however work if I cause a hot reload(but this isn't a solution).

```
  <zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="scanner"
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={converters:NegateBooleanConverter}}"
                        IsScanning="{Binding IsScanning}" 
                        IsAnalyzing="{Binding IsAnalyzing}"
                        Result="{Binding Result, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        Options="{Binding Options}"
                        ScanResultCommand="{Binding ScanCommand}"/>
```

If I use version 2.3.2 the exact same code works and the ScanResultCommand is called with no issues
but in 2.4.1 the scan just never fires.

Comment: Hi , you can share the error info here if there be , it will be helpful to check .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, there isn't really an error. It just never scans. The common solution I found is to just downgrade to the previous version. Just curious if there are other solutions people have found since the scan seems to work if you Hot reload(but this is a testing feature) so it would be nice to know why or something besides that the latest version just has bugs and one should accept using the previous version.